# ajax call failed to give response in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

hai im working in wordpress the simple concept is if the changing password if the user enters the existing password wrong need to alert the user im trying it with json message, response is receiving as undefined unable to parse the data from response.

```
function choice_update_password(){
    global $wpdb;
    $old_password=$_REQUEST['old_password'];
    $N_password=$_REQUEST['new_password'];
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $encrypt_pass= $user->data->user_pass;

     if ($user && wp_check_password( $old_password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) ) {
        wp_set_password($N_password, $user->ID);
        $url="profile";
        $view_profile=site_url($url);
        echo json_encode(array("type"=>"success","data"=>"","url"=> $view_profile));
        die();
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array("type"=>"failure","data"=>""));
        die();
    }
}
```

and the ajax part

```
function mail_prop_update($clsfrm) {
  var $form = jQuery($clsfrm),$dataType = "json";
  $form.on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e) {
    var $elements = $form.find('input:not(input[type="submit"],input[type="button"],input[type="hidden"],input[type="file"],input[type="text"].not-required),textarea#message');
    var $bool = $elements.validate();
    var email = $form.find('input[type="email"]').val();
    var action = $form.find('input[name="action"]').val();
    if ($bool) {
      ajax_submit($form, $elements, $dataType);
    }

    alert(e.responseText.type);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Are you getting any error or something else.

Comment: code is working but couldn't display error..

Comment: `console.log(e.responseText)` and check browser console to check response.

Comment: it was undefined

Comment: where is `responseText` is defined? I mean in normal ajax call we define in `success(data)` to get the response in `data` variable.

Comment: ya i have the same doubt, i am very new to wordpress

Comment: Ok, So you can add your custom ajax call. I think it will be good

Comment: where is your `add_action` the evidence of the url you are submitting to? ajax_submit - this is your own custom function?